# Приглушить звук

Tags: android, exoplayer

Есть такой код, который проигрывает аудио из интернета с помощью ExoPlayer 2. Как сделать чтобы при входящем звонке звук приглушался до 0, а когда вызов окончен, возвращался до исходного?

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String stream;
    private boolean isPlay;

    private ImageButton btnPLayPause;
    private TextView txtRadio;

    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter;
    TrackSelector trackSelector;
    SimpleExoPlayer player;
    private SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnPLayPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPLayPause);
        txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRadio);

        stream = "http://193.242.149.55:8000/kfm";

        bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory streamSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveVideoTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(streamSelectionFactory);

        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, new DefaultLoadControl());
        simpleExoPlayerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(this);
        simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player_view);
        simpleExoPlayerView.setUseController(true);
        simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();
        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
        Uri streamUri = Uri.parse(stream);
        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "yourApplicationName"), bandwidthMeter);
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(streamUri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
        player.prepare(mediaSource);

        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        isPlay = true;

        if (player.getPlayWhenReady() == true) {
            btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_stop);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        NotificationManager notifManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notifManager.cancelAll();
        super.onDestroy();
        player.release();
    }

    public void onPlayPause(View view) {
        if (isPlay == true) {
            if (player.getPlayWhenReady() == true) {
                player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
                isPlay = false;
                btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
            }
        } else if (isPlay == false) {
            if (player.getPlayWhenReady() == false) {
                player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                isPlay = true;
                btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_stop);
            }
        }
    }

    public class CallReceiver extends PhonecallReceiver {

        @Override
        protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
            txtRadio.setText("Звонит!");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
        }

    }

}
```

Второй класс

```
public class PhonecallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    private static Date callStartTime;
    private static boolean isIncoming;
    private static String savedNumber;  //because the passed incoming is only valid in ringing


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //We listen to two intents.  The new outgoing call only tells us of an outgoing call.  We use it to get the number.
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
            savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
        }
        else{
            String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            int state = 0;
            if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
            }

            onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
        }
    }

    //Derived classes should override these to respond to specific events of interest
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}
    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}
    protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}

    //Deals with actual events

    //Incoming call-  goes from IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when its hung up
    //Outgoing call-  goes from IDLE to OFFHOOK when it dials out, to IDLE when hung up
    public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
        if(lastState == state){
            //No change, debounce extras
            return;
        }
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                savedNumber = number;
                onIncomingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime);
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
                if(lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    isIncoming = false;
                    callStartTime = new Date();
                    onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                }
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
                if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                    onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                }
                else if(isIncoming){
                    onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                }
                else{
                    onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                }
                break;
        }
        lastState = state;
    }

}
```

Вот что получилось. А как теперь при входящем звонке как например вывести в txtRadio какой-нибудь текст?

Comment: Вам сюда https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones.html

Answer (score 0):

Первое что нужно, это поставить ресивер на событие приема и завершение звонка.
тут есть уже готовая реализация:
https://gist.github.com/ftvs/e61ccb039f511eb288ee 
Потом, обрабатывайте методы начала и завершения звонка.
Как замьютить exoPlayer можно посмотреть тут:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27404446/mute-audio-on-exoplayer/27404447#27404447

Comment: Не подскажете какие из этих методов отвечают за входящий звонок? и исходящий