# Не изменяется текст в TextView при звонке

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь реализовать следующее: Есть `activity`, где проигрывается аудио. Хочу чтобы при входящем звонке в `TextView` появлялась одна надпись, а когда звонок завершается, чтобы была другая надпись. Делала так, но не срабатывает:

`MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String stream;
    private boolean isPlay;

    private ImageButton btnPLayPause;
    private TextView txtRadio;

    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter;
    TrackSelector trackSelector;
    SimpleExoPlayer player;
    private SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnPLayPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPLayPause);
        txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRadio);

        stream = "http://193.242.149.55:8000/kfm";

        bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory streamSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveVideoTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(streamSelectionFactory);

        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, new DefaultLoadControl());
        simpleExoPlayerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(this);
        simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player_view);
        simpleExoPlayerView.setUseController(true);
        simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();
        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
        Uri streamUri = Uri.parse(stream);
        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "yourApplicationName"), bandwidthMeter);
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(streamUri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
        player.prepare(mediaSource);

        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        isPlay = true;

        if (player.getPlayWhenReady() == true) {
            btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_stop);
        }

        CallReceiver calls = new CallReceiver();
        calls.onIncomingCallStarted(this, null, null);
        calls.onOutgoingCallStarted(this, null, null);
        calls.onIncomingCallEnded(this, null, null, null);
        calls.onOutgoingCallEnded(this, null, null, null);
        calls.onMissedCall(this, null, null);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        NotificationManager notifManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notifManager.cancelAll();
        super.onDestroy();
        player.release();
    }

    public void onPlayPause(View view) {
        if (isPlay == true) {
            if (player.getPlayWhenReady() == true) {
                player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
                isPlay = false;
                btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
            }
        } else if (isPlay == false) {
            if (player.getPlayWhenReady() == false) {
                player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                isPlay = true;
                btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_stop);
            }
        }
    }

    public class CallReceiver extends PhonecallReceiver {

        @Override
        protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
            txtRadio.setText("Звонит 1!");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
            txtRadio.setText("Звонит 2!");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
            txtRadio.setText("Звонит 3!");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
            txtRadio.setText("Звонит 4!");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
            txtRadio.setText("Звонит 5!");
        }

    }

}
```

Класс `PhonecallReceiver`

```
public class PhonecallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    private static Date callStartTime;
    private static boolean isIncoming;
    private static String savedNumber;  //because the passed incoming is only valid in ringing


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //We listen to two intents.  The new outgoing call only tells us of an outgoing call.  We use it to get the number.
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
            savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
        }
        else{
            String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            int state = 0;
            if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
            }


            onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
        }
    }

    //Derived classes should override these to respond to specific events of interest
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}
    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}
    protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}

    //Deals with actual events

    //Incoming call-  goes from IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when its hung up
    //Outgoing call-  goes from IDLE to OFFHOOK when it dials out, to IDLE when hung up
    public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
        if(lastState == state){
            //No change, debounce extras
            return;
        }
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                savedNumber = number;
                onIncomingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime);
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
                if(lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    isIncoming = false;
                    callStartTime = new Date();
                    onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                }
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
                if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                    onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                }
                else if(isIncoming){
                    onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                }
                else{
                    onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                }
                break;
        }
        lastState = state;
    }

}
```

Comment: Сам звонок должен блокироваться или нет (появляться интерфейс приема звонка) и должно работать только когда активити с плеером на переднем плане или даже если приложение закрыто?

Comment: Наталья, код в вашем вопросе идентичен коду из [Приглушить звук](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/630119/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%ba). Как так произошло? Вы над одним проектом работаете?

Answer (score 2):

Когда нет входящего звонка в `TextView callState` появляется надпись "Not ringing", когда идет дозвон - появляется надпись "Is ringing", при сбросе\окончании вызова заменяется опять на "Not ringing". Интерфейс приема звонка появляется на экране. Работает только когда активити на переднем плане. Если действия на звонок должны происходить до уничтожения активити ( если она, например, в фоне), то код из `onPause()` нужно перенести в `onDestroy()`

Для работы требуется разрешение в манифесте:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

код:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TelephonyManager tm;
    TextView callState;
    CallStateListener callStateListener;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tm = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        callStateListener = new CallStateListener();
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        callState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.callState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }

    private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: callState.setText("Is Ringing");
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE: callState.setText("Not ringing");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А как сделать чтобы работало когда активити не на переднем плане тоже?