# Уменьшить громкость при звонке

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста как при входящем звонке уменьшить звук в приложении. Есть плеер, который проигрывает аудио, нужно чтобы при входящем звонке звук автоматически уменьшался, а по окончании вызова восстанавливался. Читал что нужно воспользоваться telephonymanager, но не очень понял как. Можно небольшой примерчик?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    private TelephonyManager tm;
    TextView callState;
    CallStateListener callStateListener;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tm = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        callStateListener = new CallStateListener();
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        callState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.callState);

        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) {
                    String phoneState = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

                    if (phoneState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING) || phoneState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {

                        ringing();

                    } else if (phoneState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {

                        notRinging();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
        registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }

    private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: callState.setText("Is Ringing");
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE: callState.setText("Not ringing");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void notRinging() {

        // действия, когда телефон закончил звонок
        Log.i(TAG, "notRinging: ");
        callState.setText("notRinging");
    }

    private void ringing (){

        // действия, когда телефон звонит или по нему разговаривают
        Log.i(TAG, "ringing: ");
        callState.setText("ringing");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
}
```

Comment: Какой то странный код и повторяется уже в третий раз, где вы его берете? или вы, Наталья и Alex один и тот же человек ... Вот в [этом ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/631524/177345) есть работающий код с реакцией на входящий звонок. Вместо вывода сообщений делайте в нужных местах увеличение или уменьшение громкости

Comment: Я нашел этот код в этом ответе. И решил пока как есть его применить чтобы посмотреть выводятся ли в textEdit эти сообщения. Ваш ответ там я честно говоря не смотрел. т.е.после case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: callState.setText("Is Ringing"); я могу написать код, для уменьшения звука и все будет работать?

Comment: Работает! В том вопросе вы пишите что будет работает только когда активити на переднем плане. А как сделать так чтобы работало и когда активити не на переднем плане? т.е. если я нажму кнопку "домой" приложение сворачивается, но продолжает играть. Как в этом случае

Comment: Вообще, если в ответе из комментария выше отмену регистрации слушателя - `tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);` убрать из `onPause()` и перенести в `onDestroy()` то этот код должен будет работать до уничтожения активити, то есть даже если она будет не на переднем плане.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы производить определенные действия, когда телефон звонит или по нему разговаривают независимо от того находится активити на переднем плане или нет, нужно в активити зарегистрировать ресивер на событие звонка и снимать регистрацию ресивера, когда активити будет уничтожена:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) {
                    String phoneState = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

                    if (phoneState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING) || phoneState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {

                        ringing();

                    } else if (phoneState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {

                        notRinging();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
        registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
    }

    private void notRinging() {

        // действия, когда телефон закончил звонок
        Log.i(TAG, "notRinging: ");
    }

    private void ringing (){

        // действия, когда телефон звонит или по нему разговаривают
        Log.i(TAG, "ringing: ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
}
```

В манифест добавляем разрешение:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: т.е. в методах notRinging() и ringing () я пишу код для уменьшения и увеличения звука и будет работать? Я просто сейчас с телефона сижу не смогу потестировать.

Comment: Обновил свой вопрос и вставил то что у меня получилось. Если активити не на переднем плане не сработало.

Comment: Я так тоже пробовал. Скопировал код и в метод добавил callState.setText("notRinging"); при запуске приложения я так понимаю в TextView должно быть notRinging, но там ничего не отображается.

Comment: При работе ресивера "notRinging" будет после сброса\отмены\завершения звонка, а не при запуске приложения - это не слушатель на событие, а действие по уведомлению. При старте никакого уведомления не приходит, потому что никакой звонок не завершен. В комментарии в методе написано когда он будет вызван. При дозвоне\разговоре будет "ringing"

Comment: попробовал сейчас. Не сработало. Когда активити на переднем плане и когда нет тоже не сработало. В логе ведь тоже должно отобразиться notRinging, ничего не происходит. В манифесте не нужно ничего дополнительно прописывать?

Comment: да, в манифесте надо. Обновил вопрос. Смотрите так же новый комментарий к вопросу.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> - это стояло у меня и так в манифесте. Я думал еще что-то может нужно добавить. с этим разрешением тоже не срабатывало через ресивер

Comment: Трудно сказать, почему у вас не работает, может в логе стоят фильтры - попробуйте какой-нибудь `Toast`выводить. Я тестировал этот код и он 100% рабочий. Попробуйте с кодом из другого ответа то, что в последнем комментарии под вопросом

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: тот вариант срабатывает. Перенес отмену регистрации слушателя в метод onDestroy(). У вас получилось небольшое решение. На некоторых сайтах смотрел там создавались классы наследники от Service, еще  какой-то класс. Не думал что так просто отлавливается окончание звонка и когда звонят. Спасибо.

Comment: Код в этом ответе тоже рабочий. Сервис используется, когда контроль за состоянием не должен зависить от существования активити.

Comment: понял. Но почему-то у меня не заработал второй вариант. Попозже еще раз протестирую второй вариант.